# Filtrar fila en una columna dependiendo del valor de otra columna

Tags: r

Tengo una base de datos con columnas de fecha y nombres, quiero filtrar en R solo los nombres siempre y cuando estén en la última fecha.

Por ejemplo tengo esta base de datos

```
NOMBRE = c("MARIO", "JOSE","JULIO", "ROSA", "MANUEL", "OSCAR")

NOMBRE = rep(NOMBRE, c(4, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1))

periodo = c(2018:2021, 2019:2020, 2020:2021, 2019:2021, 2018:2021)

df <- data.frame(periodo, NOMBRE)

> head(df)
  periodo NOMBRE
1    2018  MARIO
2    2019  MARIO
3    2020  MARIO
4    2021  MARIO
5    2019   JOSE
6    2020   JOSE
```

Quiero que el resultado sea la siguiente base.

```
periodo1 <- c(2018:2021,2020:2021,2019:2021, 2021)

NOMBRE1 = c("MARIO", "JULIO", "ROSA", "OSCAR")

NOMBRE1 = rep(NOMBRE1, c(4, 2, 3, 1))


df1 <- data.frame(periodo1, NOMBRE1)

> head(df1)
  periodo1 NOMBRE1
1     2018   MARIO
2     2019   MARIO
3     2020   MARIO
4     2021   MARIO
5     2020   JULIO
6     2021   JULIO
```

Answer (score 2):

Usando tidyverse, se me ocurre lo siguiente:

Primero definimos la fecha máxima de manera global

```
max_fecha = max(df$periodo)
```

Luego agrupamos por nombre y filtramos solo los grupos que contengan algún valor en periodo que pertenezca a la fecha máxima

```
library(dplyr)

 df %>%
    group_by(NOMBRE) %>%
    filter(any(periodo == max_fecha))
```

Answer (score 1):

Con R base la selección clásica se hace de la siguiente forma:

```
df[periodo==max(df$periodo),]
```

o bien, usando `subset()`:

```
subset(df, periodo == max(periodo))
```

Answer (score 1):

Una opción con R-base, usando el operador `%in%`

```
nombres = df[periodo==max(periodo), "NOMBRE"]

df1 = df[NOMBRE %in% nombres, ]

> head(df1)
periodo NOMBRE
1    2018  MARIO
2    2019  MARIO
3    2020  MARIO
4    2021  MARIO
7    2020  JULIO
8    2021  JULIO
```